# How do I have route helpers use existing params?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

Sometimes I won't have to provide a param to a route helper and it automagically pulls it in from the existing params. I can't seem to figure out how to get it to consistently work.

routes.rb:

```
  scope ':admin_id', module: :admin do
    resources :roles
  end
```

When rendering a page where the `:admin_id` is set to `10`:

```
<%= roles_path %>                             # /10/roles
<%= edit_role_path(my_role, admin_id: 10) %>  # /10/roles/15/edit
<%= edit_role_path(my_role) %>                # sometimes works
```

rails
routes:

```
     roles GET      /:admin_id/roles(.:format)                                                                roles#index
           POST     /:admin_id/roles(.:format)                                                                roles#create
  new_role GET      /:admin_id/roles/new(.:format)                                                            roles#new
 edit_role GET      /:admin_id/roles/:id/edit(.:format)                                                       roles#edit
      role GET      /:admin_id/roles/:id(.:format)                                                            roles#show
           PATCH    /:admin_id/roles/:id(.:format)                                                            roles#update
           PUT      /:admin_id/roles/:id(.:format)                                                            roles#update
           DELETE   /:admin_id/roles/:id(.:format)                                                            roles#destroy
```

Comment: What does this route look like in the `rake routes` output?

Comment: Also, does `my_role` happen to define `admin_id` as an attribute?

Comment: If want to make a request to a route that requires two different dynamic values in the path, you should always be passing it both those values. You could try inserting a binding and see what's available to `resource` in the places where it doesn't work but, again, you should really always be passing both of those values. These might help you:
https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#path-and-url-helpers
https://medium.com/@jaredrayjohnson1/4-things-i-learned-toying-around-with-nested-resources-in-rails-fed6d761e924

Comment: Basically trying to avoid always specifying the :admin_id param. Sometimes I don't have to, but sometimes I do. Trying to figure out the pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out!

```
def default_url_options(options={})
  { admin_id: params[:admin_id] }
end
```

This will add the param to all of my route helper methods so I don't have to specify it each time.